# MsBuild detect if current build is a nuget restore

Tags: msbuild, nuget

Is there any reliable MsBuild property which is set during a NuGet Restore - both on .NET Framework and on .NET Core?
Thus I could write things like `<Target Condition=" '$(IsCurrentBuilNugetRestore)' == 'true' " />`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that there is no built-in property indicating a restore.

The longer answer is that MSBuild works by building a dependency graph of targets and `Restore` is just a target. A given 'build' will execute many targets. One of the targets could be the Restore target.

The following command runs the Restore target and targets linked to the Restore target.

```
msbuild /t:restore example.sln
```

The following command runs the Build target and targets linked to the Build target. But the Build target typically invokes the Restore target before the actual build.

```
msbuild /t:build example.sln
```

To inject your own targets into the dependency graph, use `BeforeTargets` and `AfterTargets`.

```
<Target Name="CustomBeforeRestore" BeforeTargets="Restore">
    <Message Text="in CustomBeforeRestore" />
    ...
</target>

<Target Name="CustomAfterRestore" AfterTargets="Restore">
    <Message Text="in CustomAfterRestore" />
    ...
</target>
```

This question asked about MSBuild detecting a restore, presumably (from the example) when MSBuild is building a project.

Comment: I think `CustomBeforeRestore` could work for me, great idea. Thank you very much!

Comment: No it did not work. My Target with `AfterTargets="Restore"` did not get executed when done a nuget restore from IDE, neither when done with `nuget.exe restore`

Comment: MSBuild and NuGet are separate tools. MSBuild wraps some NuGet functionally but not the other way around. Running a restore in NuGet (e.g. `nuget.exe restore`) doesn't invoke MSBuild.

Comment: It surely has to do some msbuild work, because if you put a Target into InitialTargets, that gets executed during a `nuget.exe restore`

Comment: I see your point and I'm working on a revision to my answer. Can you provide more detail about what you want to have happen on a restore?

Comment: I want to be able to execute arbitrary Targets depending on if the current msbuild run executes a nuget restore, or not. So it should execute after a nuget restore, but should not execute in normal builds. It copies files from the nuget into the consuming project

Comment: What about if I run `dotnet.exe build`? Is `BeforeTargets="Restore"` supposed to apply there too? Because on my end it doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.